# How UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState works with -[UIScrollView zoomToRect:animated:]?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation

I have `UIScrollView` which can zoom an `UIView`. One time I want to zoom out to the default state.

Here is my code.

```objective-c
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
    [scroll zoomToRect:self.view.bounds animated:NO];
} completion:nil];
```

Wow. It jumps like hell. Seems like it sets `zoomScale = 1` and then animating the frame.

I'll add a line.

```objective-c
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
    [scroll zoomToRect:self.view.bounds animated:NO];
} completion:nil];
```

Works just fine. So how `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` helps in this case? From help I know

> Start the animation from the current setting associated with an already in-flight animation.

But there is NO in-flight animations.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer, it looks expedient but work fine.

write animation code in other place use method like 'performSelector:'

then it recognize correct current state

Comment: Let me point out if my grammar is wrong. i`m not good at english